# Batch file that look inside a txt file and find permission denied from txt and then print next 10 lines

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch script that will look inside a txt file and search for "permission denied" string from it.

If script will find above string then it will print next 10 lines which are available after search string("permission denied").

below is the code that I am trying but it is not providing required results:

```
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"permission denied" %temp%') do                 (
echo %%a
set /A after=%%a
set nextline=!after!+1
set "numbers=!after!:"
echo !numbers!
echo %nextline%
)
rem Search for the lines
for /F "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %temp% ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do echo %%~nb
```

The above code us generating only line numbers. not the content.

Comment: Is PowerShell an option? Because `powershell -command "Select-String -Context 0,10 'permission denied' '%temp%'"` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /a printLines=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%l IN (<your log file>) DO (
    SET line=%%l
    SET line=!line:permission denied=!
    IF NOT %%l==!line! SET /a printLines=11
    IF !printLines! GTR 0 (
        ECHO %%l
        SET /a printLines=!printLines!-1
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: There is a problem. This code looks for the key word `denied` instead of `permission denied`. I hope this is enough and will work. If you realy need `permission denied`, tell me and I'll update the code but it will become ugly.

Comment: Yes Michael, My task needs to use "permission denied". It would be best if it will work for complete string

Comment: and I tried with above code and it is printing all the lines. Permission denied is somewhere in the .txt file and, script need to check for the search string if it is available then it will print next 10 lines after serach string..

Comment: @MichaelS your code will not print the whole line.  By default the FOR /F will use the default delimiters and break up the line if it has spaces.  You should be able to change your SET substring to permission denied and still get the same affect.

Comment: @MichaelS, I believe the user wants the next 10 lines after the permission denied line.  So put the IF NOT after the IF GTR line and change the printLInes to start at 10.

Comment: Working as expected.. :) Thanks Michael

Comment: Michael, Is there any similar way to print 10 lines, before the search string

Comment: Yes, there is but it's quite messy. You could create 10 variables and overwrite them inside your `FOR /F` loop one by one storing the last 10 lines in them. As soon as you find your search string you echo the ten last lines you've saved. As I've said, it's not very pretty. If the code is not obvious to you, post a new question and I'll give you the code by tomorrow if noone else answers it till then.

Answer (score 1):

10 lines after

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set temp=input.txt
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"permission denied" "%temp%"') do (
    set /a start=%%a + 1
    set /a end=%%a + 10
)
FOR /L %%I IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO SET LINES=!LINES! %%I:
FOR /F "TOKENS=* delims= " %%G in ("!lines!") DO SET lines=%%G 

echo %lines%

rem Search for the lines
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%temp%" ^| findstr /B "%lines%"') do echo %%b
pause
```

10 lines before

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set temp=input.txt
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"permission denied" "%temp%"') do (
    set /a start=%%a - 10
    set /a end=%%a -1
)
IF %start% lss 1 set start=1
FOR /L %%I IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO SET LINES=!LINES! %%I:
FOR /F "TOKENS=* delims= " %%G in ("!lines!") DO SET lines=%%G 

echo %lines%

rem Search for the lines
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%temp%" ^| findstr /B "%lines%"') do echo %%b
pause
```

Comment: @PRAX, not sure what to tell you.  I have tested it on my computer several times and it works just fine.

Comment: @PRAX, you are not showing us all of the code you are using in your original question.  You do not show us how the %temp% variable is being defined and where.  Without seeing all of your code it would be very hard to troubleshoot.  I highly advise that you do not use %temp% as a variable because you are then overwriting they system variable named %temp%.

Comment: It is printing echo off after each line..:(

Comment: @PRAX, how can it go from working to not working?  Are you using the code exactly as I gave it to you without modifying it.  If you are changing the code or inserting it into existing code you have, there is no way for me to troubleshoot that problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest/simplest method to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "temp=input.txt"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"permission denied" "%temp%"') do set "line=%%a"

set lines=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('more +%line% "%temp%"') do (
   echo %%a
   set /A lines+=1
   if !lines! equ 10 goto break
)
:break
```

To show the 10 lines *before* the matching line, just change `do set "line=%%a"` by `do set /A "line=%%a-11"`, and add this line below first for: `if %line% lss 0 set "line=0"`

Comment: Aacini, the more command will not work with a negative number so you will need to check to make sure line is at least 1 to find the previous 10 lines.